# Requested a small change in the code

Tags: environments, auto-multiple-choice

I am not an expert user of TeX. I want to make a small change in the code below according to my need. The option for choices is

```
\choise0 for wrong answer and
\choice1 for the correct answer
```

How do I make it

```
 \choise for wrong answer and
 \correctchoice for the correct answer
```

I also want display the answers at the end.
Thank you for all the help and time.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\newlength{\choiceslen}

\newif\ifshowcorrect
\newcounter{choices}
\newcommand{\choicefinal}[1]{%
\ifnum\value{choices}>0 \hfill\fi\egroup
\hspace{0pt}%
\hbox to\choiceslen
\bgroup
\stepcounter{choices}%
\ifcase#1\relax
(\Alph{choices})%
\else
\ifshowcorrect
  \expandafter\underline
\fi
{(\Alph{choices})}%
\fi\space}
\newcommand{\choicetemp}[1]{\stepcounter{choices}\space(\Alph{choices})\cr}

\NewEnviron{choices}
{\setcounter{choices}{0}%
\let\choice\choicetemp
\settowidth{\choiceslen}{\vbox{\halign{##\hfil\cr\BODY\crcr}}}
\ifdim\choiceslen>.5\textwidth
\setlength{\choiceslen}{\textwidth}%
\else
\ifdim\choiceslen>.25\textwidth
  \setlength{\choiceslen}{.5\textwidth}%
\else
  \setlength{\choiceslen}{.25\textwidth}%
\fi
\fi
\let\choice\choicefinal
\setcounter{choices}{0}%
\begin{flushleft}
\bgroup\BODY\hfill\egroup
\end{flushleft}}

\begin{document}
\showcorrecttrue
\begin{choices}
\choice0 apple
\choice1 banana
\choice0 orange
\choice0 pear
\end{choices}


\begin{choices}
\choice0 apple
\choice0 banana
\choice0 orange  
\choice1 pear
\end{choices}

%\showcorrecttrue

\begin{choices}
\choice0 apple
\choice0 banana
\choice1 orange, eeeeeeeee, eeeeeeeee, eeeeeeeee
\choice0 pear
\end{choices}

\begin{choices}
\choice0 apple
\choice1 banana
\choice0 orang, eeeeeeeee
\choice0 pear
\end{choices}


\begin{choices} 
\choice0 
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
This is a very long question. This is a very long question. This is a very long question. This is a very long question. This is a very long question. This is a very long question. 
\end{minipage}
\choice0 
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
This is a very long question. This is a very long question. This is a very long question. This is a very long question. This is a very long question. This is a very long question. 
\end{minipage}
\choice0 
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
This is a very long question. This is a very long question. This is a very long question. This is a very long question. This is a very long question. This is a very long question. 
\end{minipage} 
\choice0 
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
This is a very long question. This is a very long question. This is a very long question. This is a very long question. This is a very long question. This is a very long question. 
\end{minipage}
\end{choices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You add the the tag auto-multiple-choice, but you know [Auto Multiple Choice (AMC)](https://project.auto-multiple-choice.net/)?  AMC can make exams with or without shuffled questions and answers for every student and with the same LateX document also make a solutions document or show the correct choices for every suffled sheet.  Maybe is far of your final goals, but better check that reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

Below I define `\shorthandchoice` that updates `\choice` to default to `\choice{0}` and `\correctchoice` to `\choice{1}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ}
\newlength{\choiceslen}

\newif\ifshowcorrect
\newcounter{choices}
\newcommand{\choicefinal}[1]{%
  \ifnum\value{choices}>0 \hfill\fi\egroup
    \hspace{0pt}%
    \hbox to\choiceslen
    \bgroup
    \stepcounter{choices}%
    \ifcase#1\relax
      (\Alph{choices})%
    \else
      \ifshowcorrect
        \expandafter\underline
      \fi
      {(\Alph{choices})}%
    \fi\space
}
\newcommand{\choicetemp}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{choices}%
  \space(\Alph{choices})\cr
}

\NewEnviron{choices}{%
  \setcounter{choices}{0}%
  \let\choice\choicetemp
  \shorthandchoice% <---------- Add \choice shorthand
  \settowidth{\choiceslen}{\vbox{\halign{##\hfil\cr\BODY\crcr}}}
  \ifdim\choiceslen>.5\textwidth
    \setlength{\choiceslen}{\textwidth}%
  \else
    \ifdim\choiceslen>.25\textwidth
      \setlength{\choiceslen}{.5\textwidth}%
    \else
      \setlength{\choiceslen}{.25\textwidth}%
    \fi
  \fi
  \let\choice\choicefinal
  \shorthandchoice% <---------- Add \choice shorthand
  \setcounter{choices}{0}%
  \begin{flushleft}
    \bgroup\BODY\hfill\egroup
  \end{flushleft}
}

\newcommand{\shorthandchoice}{%
  \let\oldchoice\choice
  \renewcommand{\choice}{\oldchoice{0}}
  \def\correctchoice{\oldchoice{1}}
}

\begin{document}

\showcorrecttrue
\begin{choices}
  \choice apple
  \correctchoice banana
  \choice orange
  \choice pear
\end{choices}

\begin{choices}
  \choice apple
  \choice banana
  \choice orange  
  \correctchoice pear
\end{choices}

%\showcorrecttrue

\begin{choices}
  \choice apple
  \choice banana
  \correctchoice orange, eeeeeeeee, eeeeeeeee, eeeeeeeee
  \choice pear
\end{choices}

\begin{choices}
  \choice apple
  \correctchoice banana
  \choice orang, eeeeeeeee
  \choice pear
\end{choices}

\begin{choices} 
  \choice 
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
    This is a very long question. This is a very long question. This is a very long question. 
    This is a very long question. This is a very long question. This is a very long question. 
  \end{minipage}
  \choice 
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
    This is a very long question. This is a very long question. This is a very long question. 
    This is a very long question. This is a very long question. This is a very long question. 
  \end{minipage}
  \choice 
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
    This is a very long question. This is a very long question. This is a very long question. 
    This is a very long question. This is a very long question. This is a very long question. 
  \end{minipage} 
  \choice 
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
    This is a very long question. This is a very long question. This is a very long question. 
    This is a very long question. This is a very long question. This is a very long question. 
  \end{minipage}
\end{choices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Werner. How can I show all the answers at the end. I don't want underline the answers in the questions itself. Rather I want to display at the end.

Comment: @Kumarm: I'd suggest asking that as a new question since it seems like a complete departure form this one that just asks for a different interface.